# How to solve this, Exception caught during execution of merge command. org.eclipse.jgit.errors.LockFailedException?

Tags: git, exception

When I pull using git this exception appears and I don't know what its say that **Cannot lock /home/user/location/.git/index**.

org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: Exception caught during execution of merge command. org.eclipse.jgit.errors.LockFailedException: Cannot lock /home/user/location/.git/index

[image]

Answer (score 18):

For a record, Yes I already solved it, I just manually deleted **/home/user/location/.git/index.lock**. It works for me, but just remember you can find your **.git/index.lock** to the location where you've installed your git.

Answer (score 3):

The above solution works really well. Actually, when you read the error message carefully it indicates something like this

- C:\talend\6.3.1\Talend-Studio-20161216_1026-V6.3.1\workspace.repositories\1015322431.git\talend\master\

index

follow the path your local machine and look for *index.lock* Go ahead and delete it.